# How to fill in form data, submit form, and download response ZIP file automatically in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a Python script that can navigate to this [page](https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm), fill up the form data, submit the form and download a ZIP file that is returned automatically.

the file I need is generated by selecting **Bhavcopy** in the form along with providing a valid date from the past.
[A sample input and result has been shown here[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdaaz.png)

So far I have tried to learn and implement several approaches using using Scrapy, webbrowser, requests, Beautifulsoup, Mechanize and Selenium by copying and modifying example codes from the documentations but haven't been able to make any progress.

So far the only code that worked without errors is :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
u = 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/all_daily_reports.htm'
p = requests.get(u)
soup = BeautifulSoup(p.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
d = requests.get(link.get('href'))
print(d)
```

This code is no where complete and I don't how to proceed.
Logically I know I should be:

1. fetching the page [done]
2. selecting form elements [not done] maybe doable in Scrapy
3. filling in data ( the 1st parameter is constant the date can be supplied in a loop) [have no clue how to do this programatically]
4. submitting the form [same as above]
5. clicking on the *a* tag to download the file in the *href* attribute [a request.get(on the *href* value) should do it

Any pointers to how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

The webpage allows you to download a daily report called the Bhavcopy that contains the Open, Low, High, Close data of all stocks that traded in the National Stock Exchange (India) and i wish to accumulate as much historical data as possible.

Comment: You can refer `nser` package to download historical bhavcopy. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nser/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aim is to download the zip file after providing the date, this will do the job.

If you inspect the zip file element, you can see that the href is `/content/historical/EQUITIES/2018/FEB/cm02FEB2018bhav.csv.zip` or `/content/historical/EQUITIES/2017/DEC/cm06DEC2017bhav.csv.zip` as per the date you enter.

If you look closer at the links, you can see that formatting the links is pretty easy. So, your program changes from going to the url, submitting the data and getting the zip file to simply formatting the url.

Using the url `https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2017/DEC/cm06DEC2017bhav.csv.zip`, you can directly download the zip file.

```
import webbrowser

def download_zip(date, month, year):
    url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/{2}/{1}/cm{0}{1}{2}bhav.csv.zip'.format(date, month, year)
    webbrowser.open(url)

download_zip('02', 'FEB', '2018')
```

Calling the `download_zip` function will directly download the zip file.

The only thing you have to take care of is the format of the parameters. Date format is `DD`, month is `MMM` and year is `YYYY`. Obviously, this program will throw exceptions if the url is invalid. Take care of that and handle them using try/except.

---

If you don't want the browser to pop open for the download, you can download the file using `requests` module.

```
def download_zip(date, month, year):
    url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/{2}/{1}/cm{0}{1}{2}bhav.csv.zip'.format(date, month, year)
    r = requests.get(url)
    location = 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/'  # Change the location as per your OS and your needs.
    filename = 'cm{}{}{}bhav.csv.zip'.format(date, month, year)  # You can name this file anything you want, but with a .zip extension
    with open(location + filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer . The code worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. I really like the way you wrote this code, its very clean.